# Execute javascript callback from within "script" tag after loading a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute a javscript callback from within the `<script>` tag after loading a javascript file, using query string `callback=MyCallbackFuntion`.

Something similar to

```
<script src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/USER/uploads?
        alt=json-in-script
        &max-results=30
        &callback=listVideosCallback" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here at the end of `src=http://...`, youtube uses the query string `?callback= listVideosCallback` to execute the function `listVideosCallback()` after the data/file is loaded. How can I do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server script should do something like (this example is PHP):

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');';
```

[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

When you use `<script src="URL"></script>`, the browser downloads the URL, and then executes the Javascript code that it contains. If that code looks like:

```
MyCallbackFunction(data);
```

then loading the script will cause the function to be called with the data as a parameter. So the server script should get the function name from the `callback` URL parameter, and turn it into a function call by putting parentheses and a literal data object after it and echoing this.

Comment: Don't forget the empty parenthesis ;)

Comment: Where exactly should this line go ?!

Comment: In the server script that you're running with the `<script>` tag.

Comment: I've added some more explanation, I hope it helps.

Comment: make no sense to me